# interaction between statusCode and error/success in jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-codes

Many tutorials, like [this one](https://riptutorial.com/jquery/example/1157/handling-http-response-codes-with---ajax--), suggest that it's sometimes useful to have a statusCode argument on top of the success and error methods. However, I fail to find technical details on its execution.

- Are we guaranteed the order of execution between the `statusCode{2xx:...}` and the success function?
- Are we guaranteed the order of execution between the `statusCode{4xx:...,5xx:...}` and the error function?
- Are there other technical details I should be aware of, which makes this statusCode different from having the error routine use `switch(jqXHR.status) {case 400: ...}`?
- Can I somehow specify something in the `statusCode` part that will change/stop the processing in the error/success functions, or are these fully independent?
- Does the answer to the above questions change if we use .done() and .fail(), vs ajax's arguments `error` and `success`?

Comment: From [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), the jqXHR object is a `a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object.` So I don't expect the `statusCode` to be different in both `success` callback and `.done()` resolved promise. I can't tell about the "order of execution" if both are used.... But it sounds like weird to use both. It normally should be one or the other. I *"feel"* like there is no difference... But just a code writing "style"  difference for clarity...

Comment: My question is not "success's statusCode" vs ".done()'s statusCode", my question is about ajax's property `statusCode` which can be used standalone, or together with `success`/`error`, or together with `.done()`/`.fail()`, or together with both `success`/`error` and `.done()`/`.fail()` (which I agree doesn't make sense, but that's not my concern, my question is focused on the first three cases). Does that make sense?

Comment: *"ajax's property `statusCode` which can be used standalone"* ? How you do that?

Comment: I have to admit I haven't tried that in particular, but if it's not possible, that only strengthens my question: then any use of statusCode must definitely come together with `success`/`error` (or `.done()`/`.fail()`) which means we have two things that get executed on success (`success` and `statusCode[200]`), without any documentation (that I know of) on which one will trigger first etc. Same for errors.

Comment: We're talkin about an asynchrnous request. That is a promise. When it resolves, there is ONE status code received. Be it handled by the build-in callbacks OR by a promise handler like `.done()`... My understanding is that status code is used internally my $.ajax to decide the callback to use... And is also used by the `.done` and `.fail()` promise handlers to decide to trigger or not.